# converting a String into a String array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I simply cannot find how to do this.
so, I have a String that will be something like this:

```
do this
then do that
then more of this
```

and I need to turn this into an array of strings. where every new line is needs to be a separate entry in the array. I need this done so I can process every line or command separately. I can't enter it directly into an array because this is loaded from a text document, and there is some code that removes comments and unnecessary empty lines, and a few more things with the string before it needs to become an array.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = "do this\nthen do that\nthen more of this";
String[] split = s.split("\n");
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! I really didn't know it was that easy!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string.split("(?m)\n");
```

Comment: Just curious, how does it differ `split("\n")`? (I'm always looking to learn new regex tricks :)